# Using variables for paths in shell

Tags: shell, path, cd

I want to write a cript for a user to set an installation path.
I am using this

```
read $file_path
cd $file_path
```

But it does not change to the path saved on that variable.
How can i set this exactly because this seems the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

`read` does not use the `$` to read the variable. Hence, it should be

```
read file_path
cd $file_path
```

Comment: same problem even when i change to this

Comment: @user2250162 Does the path exist? Try to do `echo $file;path ls $file_path` to see if it gets it properly.

Comment: echo prints the path,but cd does not change directory

Comment: Do you use absolute or relative path, @user2250162?

Comment: Try `cd "$file_path"`, that is, inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat reading between the lines, I think you are trying to call a script which you expect to change directory of the *caller*:  For example:

myscript:

```
read file_path
cd "$file_path"
```

command-line:

```
./myscript
```

and you find it hasn't changed the directory.  That's because you are running the script in a child process.  It changes the current directory of the child, then returns to the parent, which is unaffected.

You need to *source* the file instead, that is, run the commands in the *current* process, not a separate one:

```
. ./myscript
```

Yes, notice the extra 'dot' `.` at the start.  This is generically known as the `source` command, and you can use `source` instead of 'dot' on bash and csh.